# Javascript check second item on 2d array for duplicate before push

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a max value:

```
var max = 666;
var check = 49;
```

During my math calculation I push pairs of valueS into a 2d array like this

```
arr[i].push([a,b]);
```

but all is very slow, I think it is because the array is very huge. My arr is like this

```
[ [ [ 1, 35 ],
    [ 2, 39 ],
    [ 3, 41 ],
    [ 4, 42 ],
    [ 5, 43 ],
    [ 6, 44 ],
    [ 7, 44 ],
    [ 8, 45 ],
    [ 9, 45 ],
    [ 10, 45 ],
    [ 11, 46 ],
    [ 12, 46 ],
    [ 13, 46 ],
    [ 14, 46 ],
    [ 15, 47 ],
    [ 16, 47 ],
    [ 17, 47 ],
    [ 18, 47 ],
    [ 19, 47 ],
    [ 20, 48 ],
    [ 21, 48 ],
    [ 22, 48 ],
    [ 23, 48 ],
    [ 24, 48 ],
    [ 25, 48 ],
    [ 26, 48 ],
    [ 27, 48 ],
    [ 28, 49 ],
    [ 29, 49 ],
    [ 30, 49 ]]
```

So as you can see the 1st element is progressive, the 2nd is from calc, and my idea is:

1. Push only the pairs where the second element is not present (the max one)
2. If the second element is equal to the `check` var, I'll push the `max` var for the fist element, the `check` var for the second and stop

In other words this is the expected result

```
[ [ [ 1, 35 ],
    [ 2, 39 ],
    [ 3, 41 ],
    [ 4, 42 ],
    [ 5, 43 ],
    [ 7, 44 ],
    [ 10, 45 ],
    [ 14, 46 ],
    [ 19, 47 ],
    [ 27, 48 ],
    [ 666, 49 ]]
```

Any idea about how to make it as fast as possible? Maybe it is not here the problem but I think the smaller, better it is

J

Comment: How do you get `[1, 35]` when you push `[a, a]`? Both numbers should be the same.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, edited I push [a,b]

Answer (score 0):

Use another array to keep track of the values you've already pushed:

```
  if (!(b in already_pushed)) {
    if (b == check) {
      arr[i].push([max, b]);
      break;
    } else {
      already_pushed[b] = arr[i].length;
      arr[i].push([a, b]);
    }
  } else if (a > already_pushed[b]) {
    var index = already_pushed[b];
    arr[i][index][0] = a;
  }
}
```

Full code:

```js
var max = 666;
var check = 49;

var input = [
  [1, 35],
  [2, 39],
  [3, 41],
  [4, 42],
  [5, 43],
  [6, 44],
  [7, 44],
  [8, 45],
  [9, 45],
  [10, 45],
  [11, 46],
  [12, 46],
  [13, 46],
  [14, 46],
  [15, 47],
  [16, 47],
  [17, 47],
  [18, 47],
  [19, 47],
  [20, 48],
  [21, 48],
  [22, 48],
  [23, 48],
  [24, 48],
  [25, 48],
  [26, 48],
  [27, 48],
  [28, 49],
  [29, 49],
  [30, 49]
];

var arr = [
  []
];
var already_pushed = [];
var i = 0;

for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
  var el = input[j];
  var a = el[0],
    b = el[1];
  if (!(b in already_pushed)) {
    if (b == check) {
      arr[i].push([max, b]);
      break;
    } else {
      already_pushed[b] = arr[i].length;
      arr[i].push([a, b]);
    }
  } else if (a > already_pushed[b]) {
    var index = already_pushed[b];
    arr[i][index][0] = a;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: How push the 1st element? and how to push the max value?

Comment: I added the check for `b == check`

Comment: Don't seem to works, and in this way I don't have the highest but only the fist b element

Comment: Your description doesn't match the results. You say "Push only the pairs where the second element is not present". Why does the result have `[7,44]`, since `[6,44]` is already in the results, so the second element is already present.

Comment: I always said (the max one)

Comment: I don't know if using a 2nd array to keep track of the pushed elements is fast, but how about a solution like, check with the indexof and if present, pop and push the new one?

Comment: I didn't understand that, I thought you were talking about the variable `var max = 666;`

Comment: You can put the index of the element into the `already_pushed` array, so you can replace the first element.

Comment: just see expected result, I've to push in that way. If the second element is present, I've to replace with the higher one, and if the second element is equal to the check push the var max

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130903/discussion-between-jorman-franzini-and-barmar).

Comment: Tnx seems to works, now I've only to adapt to my solution because I'm already in a for loops, in fact I push arr[i].push([a,b]); but tnx for now.

Comment: Nope, sorry but I don't know how to insert in my code. I push every single time a,b into arr[i] so I've to check every time the arr[i]

Comment: Don't forget to empty the `already_added` array before you start each iteration of the `i` loop.

Comment: Tnx, I've to try, for now I've implemented this if (arr[i].length != 0) {
 if ((arr[i][arr[i].length - 1][arr[i][arr[i].length-1].length - 1]) === b) {
  arr[i].pop();
  arr[i].push([a,b]);
 } else if (b === check) {
  arr[i].push([max,b]);
  //break;
 } else {
  arr[i].push([a,b]);
 }
} else {
 arr[i].push([a,b]);
}

Comment: But I don't know which one is the fastest!